# Find matching rows in amounts of 3 without targeting a specific number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have two database tables.
The following query is selecting rows where the member_id and type match the query, then I am joining the two tables to get only entries that don't exist in the second, or exist but don't have NULL as portfolio_id.

This is working well.

```
$this->EE->db->select('submissions.entry_id');
$this->EE->db->from('submissions');
$this->EE->db->join('judging', 'submissions.entry_id = judging.entry_id', 'left');
$this->EE->db->where('submissions.member_group', $member_group); 
$this->EE->db->where('submissions.type_id', '1'); 
$this->EE->db->where('judging.entry_id', NULL); 
$this->EE->db->or_where('judging.portfolio_id IS NOT NULL');
$query = $this->EE->db->get();
```

The final part of my query has me completely stumped.

In the first table, a column named 'portfolio_name' can have a number between 1 and 7.

I need to retrieve 3 rows that have the same number in this column. If there are only two rows that match they must be ignored, like wise if there is 4 etc

How can this be achieved, without targeting an exact number?

Thank you

Comment: if you gave the full table definitions it may be easier to help you, but i would say you have to have to do the code to find 3 and only 3 rows of the same portfolio_name as a temporary table/join.  the inner query can't be done using active records.

Comment: This is a duplicate of duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115071/active-record-3-results-found-but-only-one-being-returned