# Single array where multiple should be returned

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The following query in phpmyadmin returns three columns (entry_id) with three different entry ids as I need.

```
SELECT sub_1.entry_id, sub_2.entry_id, sub_3.entry_id
FROM exp_judging_portfolios AS jud
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub_1 ON sub_1.id = jud.rel_id_1
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub_2 ON sub_2.id = jud.rel_id_2
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub_3 ON sub_3.id = jud.rel_id_3
WHERE sub_1.member_group = $member_group
AND jud.pre = 1
GROUP BY jud.rel_id_1
```

However, when I return the results in page, I get a single array with just one of the entry ids.

Here is the code I am using to generate the results

```
$sql = "
    SELECT sub_1.entry_id, sub_2.entry_id, sub_3.entry_id
    FROM exp_judging_portfolios AS jud
    LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub_1 ON sub_1.id = jud.rel_id_1
    LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub_2 ON sub_2.id = jud.rel_id_2
    LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub_3 ON sub_3.id = jud.rel_id_3
    WHERE sub_1.member_group = $member_group
    AND jud.pre = 1
    GROUP BY jud.rel_id_1
";
    $query = $this->EE->db->query($sql);
    $submissions_portfolio = $query->result_array();    

print_r($submissions_portfolio);
```

Here is whats returned:

```
Array ( [0] => 354 )
```

Does anyone have any idea why? and if so, how to return all 3 entry ids?

Comment: Is 354 the last row? Probably it's not merging the array somewhere (in the result_array() method), so only the last result is shown in the array.

Comment: Yes, the last result. Any ideas on the fix?

Comment: Can you show us the result_array() method?

Comment: @davey Sorry, what do you mean by method?

Comment: You're calling a function here: $query->result_array(); can you show us this function?

Comment: @davey result_array() is an inbuilt codeigniter method.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: @ccdavies why do you have $this->EE->db->query ?? what is the EE for?
   when accessing different databases i have accessed them a different way to that....  I would assume it is something wrong with the connection to the database  on the Codeigniter side.  obviously the query is ok. but its result is strange. it probably means it is not running the query you think it is.

Comment: To everyone who is trying to poke at the question, please have a basic understanding of Codeigniter before asking instead of asking the OP to explain them. This is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115071/active-record-3-results-found-but-only-one-being-returned/19115530#19115530 that I have attempted to answer before.

Comment: @xiankai I already tried using  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub_1.entry_id, sub_2.entry_id, sub_3.entry_id SEPARATOR ',') but it doesn't seperate them making it useless to me. is there a way to seperate for this?

Comment: I've updated my previous answer to include a PHP function for parsing the string, but in the future if you comment on the answer it would help us to solve your problem too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you only get one result this time, is because all 3 selected ids have the same alias `entry_id`. They end up overwriting each other.

You should try naming them differently:

`SELECT sub_1.entry_id AS id_1, sub_2.entry_id AS id_2, sub_3.entry_id AS id_3`

Comment: Thank you! That never even crossed my mind. Lesson learnt! (hopefully)